# Is it possible to catch a base faultexception & retrieve original exception? C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I do realise that this is not the normal way of doing things, so I will explain a little first before asking the full question.

We are connecting to an external restful service which has 8 methods that we use. It returns a `BaseResponse` with a:

- `ResponseCode`
- `ResponseDesc`
- `Message`

If the response code is -1 the operation was successful if not the code can be any one of about +-40 errors. To alleviate having a massive switch statement in each processor, I created a `ResponseCodeHandler` which lives in the project for the external service.

This handler interprets the code and throws the relevant fault with the message as follows:

```
throw new FaultException<OfflineFault>(new OfflineFault(), errorMessage);
```

Now since it seems* that almost every error can occur on every method I want to avoid having 40 catches in each processor - almost every error will need to be handled differently and I might as well have switch everywhere. I also can't just rethrow the error since certain items need to be set if a fault is thrown.

I would like to know if something like the following is possible (Where I need to find the `OfflineFault` in the catch):

```
try
{
    throw new FaultException<OfflineFault>(new OfflineFault(), "description");
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    audit.SetStatus(AuditTransactionStatus.Error, e.Message);
    throw faultsource.Build<OfflineFault>();
}
```

The faultsource just ensures that the error is logged everywhere etc.

I realise I *could* pass the audit and faultsource through but I would prefer not to since it would be a bit hacky in the current setup.

*Still awaiting feedback from external company

EDIT: Example of catch all as requested. I created an enum for all the codes to aid readability.

```
                // all errors which must throw a offline fault
            case ResponseCodes.HostUnavailable:
            case ResponseCodes.HostTimeout:
                throw faultSource.Build<OfflineFault>(operationName, errorMessage);

                // Already registered faults
            case ResponseCodes.UsernameAlreadyRegistered:
                throw faultSource.Build<UsernameAlreadyRegisteredFault>(operationName, errorMessage);

            case ResponseCodes.CellNumberAlreadyRegistered:
                throw faultSource.Build<CellNumberAlreadyRegisteredFault>(operationName, errorMessage, ServiceFaultCode.CellNumber);

            case ResponseCodes.EmailAlreadyRegistered:
                throw faultSource.Build<EmailAlreadyRegisteredFault>(operationName, errorMessage, ServiceFaultCode.Email);
```

Comment: Take a look at the detail property given here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575596(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmm I did if I recall but since I was catching a plain FaultException there was nothing of use. Will need to check again later when I'm at my pc.

Comment: So the generic inner type changes and you have 40 of them?
i.e. `FaultException<FooError>` and `FaultException<BarError>`

Could you show an example of the sloppy 40+ catches method (perhaps with only 3 catches)

Comment: Hi James, I added the catch. As you can see I tried to group as many errors as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I could find the above is NOT possible.

If you catch the base exception you cannot retrieve the original exception type.

i.e. If you catch **Exception** you won't be able to find out that it was thrown as a **OfflineFault**.